# How to access UI objects from loaded storyboard view in swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have got a storyboard loading in a playground. It works as intended, but now I want to be able add playground code, but don't know how to access the objects in the view from the storyboard. How would I add the @IBOutput and @IBAction in the playground. I have a UILabel called label & a UIButton called button.

Here is the playground code.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

[playground view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RapaV.jpg)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it, is to set a unique tag for each of your objects.

`yourLabel.tag = 10` for example.

Then you could access it with

`var myLabel = self.view.viewWithTag(10) as? UILabel`

For your button you would do:

```
yourButton.tag = 11

var myButton = self.view.viewWithTag(11) as? UIButton

myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton){
    print("Button with tag \(sender.tag) tapped")
}
```

This code is untested, but you should be able to get the idea

Good luck